# Rules and tax impact of rolling over my work 401(k) to a self-employed 401(k)?

Tags: united-states, 401k, self-employment, rollover

Title pretty much says it all.  I am trying to do some work on the side and I wanted to put my current job's 401k money (which 95% of it was rolled over from a previous 401k) into my on 401k that I will soon be opening up.  Are there any rules against this?  Taxes?  I am under 40 yrs of age.

I want to do this so I can do a loan on the funds to buy a house.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to TD Ameritrade, 401(k) Savings (among others) are generally eligible to be rolled over into your qualified retirement plan, in this case a Simplified Standardized Individual 401(k) Profit Sharing Plan. You may need to do an intermediate roll-over, but check with your plan holder.
[Qualified Retirement Plan Adoption Agreement](http://www.tdameritrade.com/forms/TDA9104.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I would expect you to roll your old work 401k into a Traditional IRA (sometimes called a Rollover IRA if sourced from rollover funds).   This rollover can be done where there are no taxes due.

Is there a specific reason you want to roll into your self-employed 401k instead of into a traditional IRA?

Comment: So I can do a loan.